# Suggestion changing custom post type (wordpress) from portfolio to books

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a theme. The themes has a custom-post-type as portfolio. How it can be changed to some other url (such as ebooks) keeping the functionality as same.

Can anybody suggest me. ?

Comment: I wanted to say something, but this guy already said enough, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42164/974

Answer (score 0):

Using some software, such as Fileseek to find the code `register_post_type` in your theme, and then edit it as your wish.